# Having issues with CSS Modules `$style` object in Vue Template

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-modules

I am using CSS Modules in my Vue application where a section of the template requires dynamic classes but having issues rendering the class in the $style object.

I have an internal data that toggles a boolean value.

```
data() {
  return {
    upper: false,
    lower: false,
  };
},
```

In the template below, I have this

```
<div
  :class="[$style['class 1'], activeClass]">
</div>
```

Active class is computed as follows:

```
activeClass() {
  return this.$style['active-class'] = this.upper;
}
```

There are methods that handles upper and lower based on the internal logic. Though these internal data values do return expected values but I can't seem to add the `activeClass` dynamically in the template.

Comment: are you using npm / webpack to build assets and are you using any transpiler(babel) with caching enabled?

Comment: Yep, I am @ChrisMedina. I am only running into an issue where I am managing in an internal data as opposed to component API, aka, prop.

Comment: Are you following the module rules at:  https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage  ?  Try disabling babel/transpiler cache and npm run build your application .  Also make sure you have :  <style module>  </style>

Comment: Yep, following those rules as well. Rest of the templates are working just fine. For example: `base-class-[some-key` but when I need to add a modifier class `active-class` based on internal data, it does not render the modifier class. It has to do with how Vue's reactivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
export default {
  activeClass() {
    console.log($style['active-class']);
    return this.$style['active-class'] = this.upper;
    // -> "red_1VyoJ-uZ"
    // an identifier generated based on filename and className.
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.